# Lazy object in ruby

Tags: ruby, lazy-evaluation

How can I create an opbjet that's totally lazy by itself? I have a block, and I want to pass around (as a dependency) the "current value" (at call time) of the block instead of the value at dependency injection time.

I can't actually pass around a lambda because all the services expect an actual object, so they won't send `:call` to them, just access them.

This (oversimplified) example might clarify the situation:

```
class Timer
  def initialize(current_time)
    @current_time = current_time
  end

  def print_current_time
    print @current_time
  end
end

class Injector
  def current_time
    # a lazy object that when accessed actually calls the lambda below
    # every single time.
  end

  def current_time_lazy
    -> { Time.now }
  end

  def instantiate(class_name)
    # search for the class, look at the constructor and
    # create an instance with the dependencies injected by
    # name
    # but to be simple
    if class_name == "Timer"
      Timer.new(current_time)
    end
  end
end

timer = Injector.new.instantiate("Timer")
timer.print_current_time # => some time
sleep 2
timer.print_current_time # => some *different* time
```

The actual situation implies passing around the `current_user` but depending on the situation the current user might change after those values are injected.

I would really appreciate any suggestion (even if for now I will carefully sort the dependency injection code so this doesn't happen, but I think it's pretty fragile)

Comment: I don't understand "actual object" in your second paragraph, considering that lambdas are objects.

Comment: @CarySwoveland of course lambdas are objects. What I need is to be able to pass something similar to a promise in fact. So the services which get that promise/lambda/whatever will not be able to tell the difference, but I don't need to have the object at hand at injection time.

Answer (score 0):

This should help :

```
class Timer
  def initialize(current_time)
    @current_time = current_time
  end
  def print_current_time
    puts @current_time
  end
end

class LazyMaker < BasicObject
  def self.instantiate(class_name, lambada)
    if class_name == 'Timer'
      ::Timer.new(new(class_name, lambada))
    end
  end
  def initialize(class_name, lambada)
    @lambada = lambada
  end
  def method_missing(method, *args)
    @lambada.call.send(method, *args)
  end
end

timer = LazyMaker.instantiate('Timer', -> { Time.now })
timer.print_current_time # some time
sleep 2
timer.print_current_time # some other time
```

I'm trying to use delegation to implement it, so that I can call the block first, get a new object and redirect the method call to it. Why this way ? Because basically, accessing an object to do something means to call a method on it. For instance, in `print @current_time`, it sends `@current_time.to_s`.

But since almost all objects will have a few methods inherited from standard base classes in Ruby like `Object`, `LazyMaker` also has methods like `to_s`. So I thought of making just the `LazyMaker` inherit from `BasicObject`, which is a blank class. So almost all of the methods get delegated.

But yeah, there might be another way to do this.

Comment: Nice answer, like a super-lazy SimpleDelegator! I'll try it :)